# Automatically Centered Images

Tags: discussion, support, design

I like it when the images in posts are centered because for me the whole post looks a little bit more professional.

Therefore I use currently the hskip command:

```
$\hskipXin$     % with X being some real value, e.g., .5, 1, 2, ...
```

But doing this all the time manually, which includes the need to find a proper X-value that somehow centers the image, isn't that satisfying. ^^

**Theoretically**, can you tell which method I would choose to automagically center my images?

Comment: I think it's by design, that images are not centred in general and the way you choose to workaround this may look odd on different browsers/devices. Here is something related on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25835/260760

Comment: not nice from the programming gods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [@MartijnPieters Can you please tell how to align it center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow#comment13500_253405)
>
> [@SVM-RAJESH: you cannot; there are no alignment options.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow#comment13501_253405)

So, you have no official way of doing this. Instead;

- Use \hspace or \hskipxin. I prefer \hspace though. It would've been heaven if MathJax supported \rule - that really gives horizontal and vertical control over "stuff" - but no cigar.
- Use `<pre>`. This is inconsistent and/or ugly in some browsers.
- Use `&nbsp;`. Ten times a day, before each meal. Well, I'm pretty sure we're lazier off with $\LaTeX$ shortcuts.

[image]

Now, let's resize this thing:

### Using \hspace:

$\hspace{25ex}$ [image]

I used `$\hspace{25ex}$`; then stared at the image to figure out whether if it's centered or not$\ldots$ and then felt asleep. So figuring that out is your job.

### Using `<pre>`

I typed 25 spaces to achieve that. If we're too lazy for \hskipxin, then yeah$\ldots$ this isn't an option.

### Using `&nbsp;`

[image]

I don't have much to say, just that I used 48 `&nbsp;`s to align it like that.

So it's your choice which one to use.

Comment: As an alternative, you can make you pictures full width. Of course this is only possible, when you make original content or decide to resize sources from the internet.

Comment: On another note, I took a look at this answer from my android tablet's browser; the only one that actually looked centered was the `\hspace` version. Talk about inconsistency$\ldots$